# Laravel 5 Error Reporting Suppression

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling

In Laravel 4, it was easy enough to suppress E_NOTICE messages; 
I can't seem to be able to do this because if I add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)
```

anywhere it simply gets overridden.

This seems to happen around here:
(index.php)

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()

);
```

I have added custom code to handle more "pretty" views of exceptions/errors within Exceptions/Handler.php but I'm struggling to switch off notices (I don't want any of these firing off with notices at all)

- Yes, the issue should be *fixed*, I'm aware of this, however this is a case where I'd prefer the notices NOT bombing the app on live (I have a custom logging solution for this), and on dev I'd like the notice to show.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Laravel 5, we can set `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` inside the `AppServiceProviders::boot` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    //set whatever level you want
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
}
```

Comment: Dude, I was looking for a solution for this shit for almost the whole day. Thank you so much for this piece of gold, you saved me man!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `APP_DEBUG` in your `.env` file is set to false in production? That might override your `error_reporting()` call.